# how to add css style to every item of array

Tags: javascript, css

will you help me. I dont know how to add css style to every generated number from script. **I want every generated number from script has some background image.**
**Array of generated numbers is arr** . Thanks for help

Code:

**HTML:**

```
  <p onclick="myFunction()">Click HERE  "</p>
    <p id=demo> </p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
  function myFunction() {
    var arr = [];
    while(arr.length < 2)  
    {
        var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)  
        var found=false;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==randomnumber){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= arr;
}
```

Comment: ??? Numbers don't have CSS properties?

Comment: Please, give as an example of "number with background"

Comment: Here is an example how it should look like.   http://shockwave3.rajce.idnes.cz/nastenka/#example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the whole problem statement.
From what ever i understand, i could make out a solution of this.
Hope this solution helps

```js
 function myFunction() {
      var arr = [];
      while(arr.length < 2)
      {
        var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)  ;
        var element = document.createElement("span");
        var demo=document.getElementById("demo");
        element.innerText=randomnumber;
        element.className="red";
        var found=false;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          if(arr[i]==randomnumber){
            found=true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(!found) {
          arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
          demo.appendChild(element);
        }
      }
    // demo.innerHTML= arr;
    }
```

```css
    .red{background: red;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<p onclick="myFunction()">Click HERE  </p>
<p id=demo>

</p>
```